# Is it possible to create or store a Windows backup system image on a non-NTFS drive?

Tags: windows, backup, ntfs, windows-backup, time-capsule

I'm trying to use Windows Backup on Windows 7 to create a system image to a network location.  The destination, identified by UNC path, is an Apple Time Capsule formatted with HFS+.  While Windows allows this location for regular backups, it claims that system images can only be written to NTFS-formatted locations.

1. Does NTFS actually have some unique feature required to create the image, or is Windows just assuming that any non-NTFS system must be FAT32, and therefore limited to 4GB file sizes?  Could I safely create the image to an NTFS-formatted HDD, then transfer it to the Time Capsule for long-term storage?
2. Even better, is there some way to trick Windows Backup into either skipping the NTFS check, or convincing it that the Time Capsule is actually formatted as NTFS, so I can create the system image on it directly?